# ViewPager using Support and Native Fragements

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am working on an application that uses Fragments and a `ViewPager` to allow the user to swipe between a Fragement containing a preview utilizing `Camera2` API, based on `googlesamples`' [Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) example from Github. This is where the problems come in to play.

This code implementation for the Camera relies heavily on the native `Fragment` while the `ViewPager` seems to require the use of the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` It seems I require a way to implement both of these `Fragment` in the same project. On this note, I do know of the existence of the `android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat`, however, this does not seem to provide the functions/methods and functionality to work universally with the code implementation I am using.

---

**Basic Fragment Files**

*My basic `Fragment` files follow this design.*

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Recommended empty Constructor
     */
    public FriendsFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate and return the views from XML layout, don't attach to container at this time
        return (inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false));
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates and returns a new FriendsFragment
     * @return FriendsFragment instance
     */
    public static FriendsFragment newInstance() {
        return (new FriendsFragment());
    }
}
```

**Getting the Fragments**

*This basic code is how I've been handling the switching between the `Fragments` as the `ViewPager` is swiped.*

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private final int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new SwipePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    private class SwipePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SwipePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance();
                case 1:
                    return SecondFragment.newInstance();
                default:
                    return SecondFragment.newInstance();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of Fragment pages available to the {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
         * @return The number of pages
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```